# Maximum number of characters for validation does not work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Want to achieve

Thanks for watching.
I'm developing using Rails.
I have set up validates on model, but the validation of the maximum number of characters does not work properly.
company.rb

```
validates :price,
    length: { maximum: 23 },
    presence: true,
    numericality: true
```

Write it like this,
and then use the form The validation will be tripped when 23 characters (10000000000000000000000) are entered.

By the way,
22 characters (1000000000000000000000000) also tripped the validation, and
21 characters (1000000000000000000000000) passed the validation.

Form.vue

```
<template>
  <main>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>price</legend>
          <div class="form-row">
            <b-form-input class="form-control" type="text"></b-form-input>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  </main>
</template>
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "companies", id: :bigint, unsigned: true, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4", force: :cascade do |t|
  ・
  ・
  ・
  t.decimal "price", precision: 24, scale: 4
  ・
  ・
  ・
```

params (when 23 characters are entered and the validation is caught)

```
Parameters: {"price"=>"10000000000000000000000"}
```

When I looked at the parameters, they were strings, so I changed in the place where the controller receives the parameters, but it still failed to validate.

```
def create_company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(
  ).tap do |v|
    v[:price] = v[:price].to_i
  end
end
```

I don't understand why the maximum number of characters in the validation is different from what I set in the model.

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

### Environment

Ruby 2.6
Ruby on Rails 6.0

Answer (score 1):

```
t.decimal "price", precision: 24, scale: 4
```

It will give you a total of 24 digits, with 4 after the decimal point.

About the validation,
If you want that the :price should always four decimal you can try this,

```
 validates :price, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{4})?\z/ }, numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than: 999999999999999999999999 }
```

If you want that the :price should have at most four decimal or less (i.e: 7, 7.9, 7.99, 7.999, 7.9999) you can try this,

```
validates :price, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,4})?\z/ }, numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than: 999999999999999999999999 }
```

Note: less_than you can mention the maximum number you can store in db

Please follow this blog if you still seeing an issue

https://nelsonfigueroa.sh/handling-decimal-precision-in-rails/

Comment: :Thankyou! I modified it as you taught me, but it still fails to validate. (I think I typed "maximum" wrong when I asked the question). When I looked at the parameters, they were strings, so I changed v[:price] = v[:price].to_i in the place where the controller receives the parameters, but it still failed to validate.

Comment: @katahik Please check the answer, I have shared an blog URL related to your query

Comment: ＠Nataraja B Seriously, thank you, I used numericality and it worked!